# Any ADO.net alternative?

Tags: .net, ado.net

does any ADO.net alternative for .Net exist, just hypothetical? A friend of mine needs this maybe for his exam.

Comment: You can use <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx">Linq to Sql</a>.

Comment: Perhaps define more precisely what they want to replace. What are they meaning by ADO.NET? If they mean the data-adapter rubbish, then sure - lots of them; linq-to-sql, dapper, dblinq, entity-framework, nhibernate, petapoco, massive, subsonic, bltoolkit, active-record, ...

Comment: ...which sits directly on top of ADO.NET, so this isn't a *replacement*. It all depends on what the OP is actually intending to replace.

Comment: So theres not a real replacement for the ADO.net class set and it makes no sense to use any? But there a alternatives data adapters which could be used.

Comment: @AntiLamer those aren't "adapters". And you haven't told me what you interpret as "ADO.net", so I can't answer that. You might be thinking of something slightly different to what *I* would consider "ADO.net"

Comment: Put another way: what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: My friend wrote a small program for his degree, he used ADO.net for db acess and  and he's fearing that a examiners ask a question like "You used ADO.net did you considered any alternative or do you know any".

Comment: @AntiLamer and again, that is vague - what ***exactly*** does he mean by "used ADO.net" ? if he means "I used DataSet, DataTable etc" then yeah, that sucks. But that is not ADO.NET; that is a layer *on top of* ADO.NET. The equivalent would be to say "I used the File / FileStream etc classes to talk to the file-system" - those are entirely correct classes to use; why would you *not* use them. ADO.NET *itself* is just the raw wrapper around the different DB connection implementations... of course, tools like "dapper" are huge time savers *and* just as fast as doing it all yourself.

Comment: @Marc Gravell I think we got it. So asking for a ADO.NET alternative is to vague to answer. I think thats the correct answer in the exam ;)

Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: @AntiLamer that's not quite what I'm saying; I'm saying that you really haven't made it clear *as an alternative to what, ***exactly*** ;p* I still don't know *exactly* what your friend used.... which makes it very hard to say whether there are alternatives.

Comment: @Marc Gravell He used DataSet, DataTabels and DataAdapter. Thats all I know ;)

Comment: @AntiLamer - right; now *that* is something that has many alternatives, almost all of which are better ;p In terminology, that ***isn't*** ADO.NET, but a lot of people get them confused. I think it would be sensible to think of an answer to the question "Did you consider using any alternatives to DataSet / DataTable?".

Comment: @Marc Gravell Yeah, we was confused by the terminology too ;) Again thanks for your patience :)

Answer (score 1):

Although not an "alternative" You can use ODBMS as your persistance db which does not need to use Ado.net.

Answer (score 0):

I developed something about 10 years ago for VB 6 and ASP.  Last month, I updated it for .NET and it works great.  Didn't have to touch a line of code.

ADO.NET uses the older ADODB recordsets and I'm doing the same thing.  Faster, easier, maps directly to business objects.  No limitations and enforces good n-tier programming.  For some screenshots and code, take a look at http://andrewbbrown.com